# Do $c=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{13}}2$ have meaningful 2-adic valuations?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory

Do $c=\dfrac{3\pm\sqrt{13}}2$ have meaningful 2-adic valuations?

If not, is there an extension to $\lvert\cdot\rvert_2$ such that either

a) they do, or

b) such that $\lvert c\rvert_p=1/c$?

I don't know where to start with irrational padic values.

Comment: The polynomial $p(x) = x^2-3x-1$ has no solution in the field $\mathbb Q_2$ of $2$-adic numbers.  There is a natural extension of the $2$-adic valuation to the extension field $Q_2(X)/(p(X))$, and in that field your polynomial has two solutions.  There is no canonical way to choose between the two square-roofs of $13$ so that we can call one of them $+\sqrt{13}$ and the other $-\sqrt{13}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they do. In spite of the problem in GEdgar's comment.

The extension $K=\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{-3})$, also gotten by adjoining a primitive third root of unity $\omega=(-1+\sqrt{-3})/2,$ is a so called unramified extension. Implying (among other things) that:

- The ring $R=\Bbb{Z}_2(\omega)$ is the integral closure $\Bbb{Z}_2$ in $K$.
- $R$ is a local ring.
- The principal ideal $2R$ generated by $2$ is the unique maximal ideal of $R$ consisting of its non-units.
- The quotient ring $R/2R$ is isomorphic to the field of four elements $\Bbb{F}_4$, cosets represented by $0,1,\omega$ and $\omega+1\equiv\omega^2$.

The connection to your question is explained by the following:

- $-39\equiv1\pmod8$ so the field $\Bbb{Q}_2$ contains square roots of $-39$.
- Because $13=(-39)/(-3)$, the field $K$ contains $\pm\sqrt{13}$.
- The $2$-adic valuation extends to $K$: Every non-zero element $z\in K$ can be written in the form $z=2^mu$ with $u\in R^*=R\setminus2R$, and the exponent $m\in\Bbb{Z}$ then describes the $2$-adic valuation as usual. See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1283506/11619) for a description of that extension of the valuation using the norm map $N:K\to\Bbb{Q}_2$.
- The irreducible quadratic $x^2-3x-1\in\Bbb{Z}_2[x]$ has a constant term in $\Bbb{Z}_2^*$ implying that its roots are units of the ring $R$. Therefore their extended values are $|(3\pm\sqrt{13})/2|=1$. Or, if you prefer the exponential form, $\nu(c)=0$.
- Whether $\dfrac{3+\sqrt{13}}2$ is congruent to $\omega$ or $\omega+1$ modulo $2R$ depends on the choices you make when specifying the square roots (this is built into GEdgar's comment).

Worth knowing:

- Possibly surprisingly $\Bbb{Q}_2$ has only finitely many quadratic extensions. All listed locally [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/113415/11619). In Pete L. Clark's list $\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt5)=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ is this (unique) unramified extension, due to the fact that $3\cdot(-5)=-15\equiv1\pmod 8$, so $\sqrt{-15}\in\Bbb{Q}_2$.
- The other quadratic extensions are *ramified*, meaning that the element $2$ no longer generates a maximal ideal in the integral closure $\Bbb{Z}_2$ with the other extension fields.

Comment: Thank-you SO much.  In so many ways this connects up dots for me.  There are many excellent things going on here!

Comment: This is a great answer which I have come back to many times.  But I have found myself wanting to understand better what *"has only finitely many quadratic extensions"* means. By that I mean that I find myself thinking "i can add an $i$ and do arithmetic - what is stopping me?" I assume something breaks, does it, if I do that?

Answer (score 6):

This is to amend Jyrki's answer with one warning and one generalisation from a different perspective.

**Warning**: Everyone remembers from high school that the two solutions of $x^2-3x-1$ are $x_{1,2}=\frac12 (3 \pm \sqrt{13})$, where the number $13 := 3^2-4\cdot(-1)$ is the *discriminant* of the polynomial. However, in high school it's tacitly assumed that that symbol $\sqrt{13}$ means the *square root $\color{red}{\textit{in} \; \Bbb R}$*. If we look at some other extension $K$ of $\Bbb Q$, the formula for the solutions still is correct, but now we have to interpret that square root of $13$ as a *square root* $\color{red}{\textit{in} \; K}$ (if such a square root exists). I stress this because the OP has a history of mixing up real numbers with $p$-adic numbers: It's **not** the real numbers $x_{1, real} \approx 3.3027756377...$ and $x_{2, real} \approx -0.3027756377...$ which get a $2$-adic value in Jyrki's answer. It is two elements of $\Bbb Q_2(\omega)$, each of which one could write down as 
$$x_{1, \Bbb Q_2(\omega)} = (\text{some binary string}) + (\text{some other binary string})\cdot \omega$$
$$x_{2, \Bbb Q_2(\omega)} = (\text{some other binary string}) + (\text{some other binary string})\cdot \omega,$$
and it is *these* two numbers which have well-defined $2$-adic values. As long as one does *only algebra*, it is OK to just write $x_1 = \frac12(3+\sqrt{13})$ both for the real number and the $2$-adic number (to quickly compute their powers etc.). But as soon as one is interested in ordering, topology, "which of $x_1, x_2$ is closer to $5$?", ..., one should actually *not* express either the real or the $2$-adic numbers with that algebraic formula, but needs at least a little bit of their actual real, resp. $2$-adic, expansions.

(By the way, another way to express those $2$-adic solutions would be as [Witt vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witt_vector) over the finite field $\Bbb F_{2^2}$.)

**Generalisation:** Let $p$ be any prime and let $x^2+bx+c$ be a monic quadratic polynomial $\in \Bbb Q[x]$. Everyone remembers from high school that the two solutions are $x_{1,2}=\frac12 (-b \pm \sqrt{D})$, where the number $D := b^2-4c$ is the discriminant of the polynomial, and in high school $\sqrt{D}$ means the square root in $\Bbb R$, if it exists (or in cool high schools, the square root in $\Bbb C$, where it is guaranteed to exist).

Of course if $D$ is a square in $\Bbb Q$, the polynomial splits over $\Bbb Q$; if not, it might happen that $D$ is a square in $\Bbb Q_p$, or if not, then there is a quadratic extension $K$ of $\Bbb Q_p$ which contains a square root of $D$ and hence the polynomial splits (your example falls in this third situation).

Either way, the solutions $x_1$, $x_2$ have well-defined $p$-adic values, and it turns out one can read them off the values of the coefficients $b$ and $c$. (This can be done with [Vieta's formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas), or algebraic number theory, or most easily, with [Newton polygons](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/research/pdf/Newton.pdf).)

It turns out that from this perspective there are just two cases:

> *Case I*: If $v_p(b) \ge \frac12 v_p(c)$, then both solutions of $x^2+bx+c=0$ have the same value
>
> $$\lvert x_i \rvert_p = \lvert c \lvert_p^{1/2}.$$
>
> *Case II*: If $v_p(b) < \frac12 v_p(c)$, then one of the solutions has the same value as $b$, and the other the same as $c/b$:  $$\lbrace \lvert x_1 \rvert_p, \lvert x_2 \rvert_p \rbrace = \lbrace \lvert b \rvert_p, \lvert \frac{c}{b} \rvert_p \rbrace$$

Further, one can show that if the polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb Q_p$, we are in case $I$, i.e. we have $$\lvert x_i \rvert_p = \lvert c \lvert_p^{1/2}.$$

The interesting tricky case is that the polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$, but splits over $\Bbb Q_p$, and one is in case II -- user mercio brought up an example for this when I was too sloppy [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2840897/96384): For the polynomial $x^2-x+2$, one is tempted to write the two solutions as $x_{1,2} = \frac12( 1\pm\sqrt{-7})$, but that does not help much, because, just like in user GEdgar's comment, there are two numbers in $\Bbb Q_2$ whose square is $-7$; and now it turns out that we are in case II, one of the $x_i$ has $2$-adic value $\lvert x_i \rvert_2 = 1$, and the other has value $\lvert x_i \rvert_2 = 1/2$ -- but which is which in the $\pm$ formula? That question makes no sense, because it's unclear which of the two square roots of $7$ in $\Bbb Q_2$ the "$\sqrt{-7}$" in the formula refers to. What Jyrki and I figured out there was:

> If by $\sqrt{-7}$ we mean the $2$-adic number which ends in $...11$, then $\lvert \frac12( 1 + \sqrt{-7}) \rvert_2 = 1/2$ and $\lvert \frac12( 1 - \sqrt{-7}) \rvert_2 = 1$;
>
> but if by $\sqrt{-7}$ we mean the $2$-adic number which ends in $...01$, then $\lvert \frac12( 1 + \sqrt{-7}) \rvert_2 = 1$ and $\lvert \frac12( 1 - \sqrt{-7}) \rvert_2 = 1/2$.

Comment: Thanks, you were right to anticipate I might fail to make that distinction, although I also appreciated these roots sit partly in $\Bbb C$ so I'm unclear whether they're out of $\Bbb R$ "in two ways". Also, it would be helpful if "some binary string" coincided with the binary string of the real-valued root.  I imagine this must happen sometimes but the real string has an alternating or otherwise non-convergent component which messes up the padic valuation, but adjoining the roots of unity is just the right thing to sort that out.

Comment: No, the (pair of!) strings in the $2$-adic expansion of the $2$-adic solutions are totally different from the binary expansions of the real solutions. Literally the only thing they have in common is that if, according to the arithmetics of the respective expansions (in the $2$-adic case, the pair of strings and the $\omega$ intervening), you multiply them by $2$, then subtract $3$, then square, you get $13$.

Comment: As to the first question, maybe I phrased it confusingly, but the only thing going on here is that $\Bbb R \subset \Bbb C$, so the real solutions do not "sit partly" in $\Bbb C$, but simply like all real numbers, they are also complex numbers. On the other hand, $\Bbb C \cap \Bbb Q_p = \Bbb R \cap \Bbb Q_p = \Bbb Q$. Look at https://imgur.com/uE4H4eP, I marked in red where the real and where the $2$-adic solutions live. The real ones are also in $\Bbb C$, of course.

Comment: Thanks. Re $\Bbb C$ I was referring to the third root of unity added to form $\Bbb F_4$ - can that be in $\Bbb C$, i.e. $\omega\in\Bbb C$?  Although I also understand it's okay just to think of it as a character $\omega$.

Comment: No, as soon as you want to do anything more than pure algebra, that third root of unity $\omega$ in the unramified quadratic extension of $\Bbb Q_2$ should precisely *not* be thought of as one of the third roots of unity in $\Bbb C$, for the same reasons. (But "character" means something different also.) Algebraically, it is just an $x$ which satisfies $x^2+x+1=0$.

Comment: This should  possibly be the accepted answer given that I failed to take into account the history. I particularly like the example with $\sqrt{-7}$. A more senior colleague once asked me for help when he failed to make sense of a formula in a paper he was reading. His mistake was exactly to assume that $(1\pm\sqrt{-7})/2$ would be each others conjugates over $\Bbb{Q}_2$, and thus share the same valuation. Took me a while to see what the problem was, too :-)

Comment: The connections between this and the Collatz conjecture are truly intriguing. $c=3\pm\sqrt13$ are the fixed points of the function $f(x)=\dfrac{3x+p^{\nu_p(x)}}{p^{\nu_p(3x+p^{\nu_p(x)})}}$ which is a form of the Collatz graph which commutes over $c^i2^jf(x)=f(c^i2^jx)$ ($p$ here represents $2$, and $c$). Then the *ring of n-truncated p-typical Witt vectors* is also an intriguing concept given that the directed Collatz graph essentially involves truncation of sequences - the requirement being to show every positive integer has a representation.

Comment: ...although it would seem almost certain that all of $\Bbb Z[\frac16,c]$ have representations, and converge to $\langle2\rangle\cdot\Bbb F_4$ upon iteration of $f$.  Then I suppose the result we really require is that $f$ acts transitively over $\Bbb Z[\frac16,c]/\langle2\rangle\cdot\Bbb F_4$

Comment: Do I interpret this correctly that in the instance of $3\pm\sqrt{13}$, it is true that $v_2(b)=0\geq 0=\frac12v_2(c)\implies \lvert 3\pm\sqrt{13} \rvert_2 = \lvert c \lvert_p^{1/2}=\sqrt1=1$?

Comment: To the last comment, yes, matching Jyrki's answer.

Comment: This says that it's amending [Jyrki's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3258732/323585). However, that answer has been edited, and is likely to be deleted. You may want to look at the [revisions](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3258732/revisions) of that answer and pull in whatever you need to make this answer not depend on it.